# Specify default Spring profile

Tags: spring

Is there anyway to specific the default profile directly in the Spring XML

```
<beans profile="Development">
    <!-- Load Development beans -->
</beans>

<beans profile="Production">
    <!-- Load Production beans -->
</beans>
```

Note, I don't want to do this programmatically, as command-line property, environment variable or web.xml (its not a web app)

I want to do it directly in the xml something like:

```
<property name="spring.profiles.default" value="Production">
```

Comment: No, as that would also defeat the purpose of profiles if you could specify the one to use in static xml files. Just make the `Production` one the default   by not putting it in a profile based element, the `Development` one can then simply override the beans that are different from the production ones.

Comment: but there are some beans in the Production profile that will/should never get loaded in Development mode.

Production uses 3 different beans to load config from a Database.
Development only has one Bean to load config from a properties file

Comment: Then use for those beans a profile that isn't development i.e. `profile="!development"`.